# PHP file-upload using jquery post

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

Let me know if anyone know what is the issue with this code.

Basically i want to upload a file using jQuery

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(event) {
      $('#form1').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('post.php',function(data){
           $('#result').html(data);
        });
      });
    });
  </script>  
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1">
  <h3>Please input the XML:</h3>
  <input id="file" type="file" name="file" /><br/>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File"/>
</form>

<div id="result">call back result will appear here</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and my php 'post.php'

```
<?php
  echo $file['tmp_name'];
?>
```

Uploaded File name is not returned back. Issue is i couldn't access the uploaded file.

Thanks in advance!
Shiv

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Basically i want to upload a file using jQuery

You cannot upload files using AJAX. You could use the [jquery.form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin which uses a hidden iframe:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(event) {
            $('#form1').ajaxForm(function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            });
        });
  </script>  
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3>Please input the XML:</h3>
    <input id="file" type="file" name="file" /><br/>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File"/>
</form>

<div id="result">call back result will appear here</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Also notice the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form.

Another possibility is to use the [HTML5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications) which allows you to achieve that assuming the client browser supports it.

Comment: Did you mean you can't upload files using AJAX or you can't upload files using jQuery's post() method?

Answer (score 9):

It's not possible to upload files with jQuery $.post, neverthless, with the file API and XMLHttpRequest, it's perfectly possible to upload a file in AJAX, and you can even know how much data have been uploaded yet…

```
$('input').change(function() 
{
    var fileInput = document.querySelector('#file');

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/upload/');

    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) 
    {
        /* 
        * values that indicate the progression
        * e.loaded
        * e.total
        */
    };

    xhr.onload = function()
    {
        alert('upload complete');
    };

    // upload success
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0))
    {
        // if your server sends a message on upload sucess, 
        // get it with xhr.responseText
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }

    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('title', this.files[0].name);
    form.append('pict', fileInput.files[0]);

    xhr.send(form);
}
```

Comment: Sadly the support for XHR2 isn't good yet. But thanks for your input on this, I've managed to make a fully working test with Zepto and some mock data by using that approach.

Comment: All current major browers versions suport it (even IE 10+). http://caniuse.com/xhr2

Answer (score 5):

No no no, you should use a jQuery form plugin for async uploading files. You can't upload file with jQuery $.post method. The file will be uploaded with hidden iframe

Another way is to use HTML5 uploading with FileAPI/BlobApi

Comment: Thanks mate!

For now, i will just go with normal html form submit instead of jquery post. That way, it works for me!

Answer (score 2):

Your upload.php has some error.

you should change your this part.

```
echo $file['tmp_name'];
```

to:-

```
echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading with an iframe because you can't send a file with $.post method.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try jquery uploadify - http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: Why you will go with an external library, when the browser has an API for that?

Comment: Because we were talking about uploading files long time ago, I would say a century or more in terms of new technologies development. When I proposed that there were no html5 or it was just starting and anything more than pure html required flash (mostly). Uploadify was pretty good library in that time and among other features  offered progress bar, multiple files upload, drag and drop and if I recall correctly was jquery based.