# how to send ajax request to upload file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have a markup like this 
    
I am not using form for this now I want to upload an image using ajax

```
$('#file').on('change', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: ?,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
})
```

in data what I have to send? I got this ajax in stack overflow only but I am not able to understand. And one more thing how can I recive the data in PHP file

thank you?

Comment: why don't you just google it ??

Comment: you have the solution here (there is no solution using jquery post ) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046684/php-file-upload-using-jquery-post

Comment: who given me minus point as a beginner why you did this 
my question is Genuine you might know more than me that doesnt mean you are the only one

Comment: I googled it I didnt get the answer that is the reason I came here

Answer (score 1):

uploading an image via ajax isn't possible. What you can do is create a hidden iframe and upload the file using that.

Comment: It's definitely possible in modern browsers.

Comment: sorry @KevinB you are correct. If you want to support IE9 and below then its not possible. Maintiaining two solutions for this inorder to support IE9, Firefox 3 and below is quite cumbersome and you probably don't want to go that route.

Comment: Definitely a personal choice at that point. I would use the modern method of doing it, and only degrade functionality for the one browser that doesn't support it. And if you factor this functionality out into a custom method, you only have to do it once.

Answer (score 0):

do note that generally uploading files via AJAX is a pain. You can view the related question here [File Upload via AJAX within JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686099/file-upload-via-ajax-within-jquery) .

Personally, I resorted to generating a hidden iframe on submit, with a clone of the form, which gets submitted. Once done, the content of the iframe is grabbed back to jQuery. I couldn't find another way that workind in old IE versions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be accomplished in browsers that support the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) function

```
$('#file').on('change', function(e) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file',this.files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
})
```