# display image uploaded

Tags: php, html, sql

So I have this code. I am working with uploading image and I want it to be displayed after the user has uploaded it. Help me with my code please, just a PHP newbie here. :(

```
connect.php
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "12345";
$db = "demo";
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $password, $db);
if (!$con) {
   die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
}
?>
try.php here
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>

<?php
if (isset($image)) {
    $errors = array();
    $imageName = $_FILES['photoUpload']['name'];
    $imageSize = $_FILES['photoUpload']['size'];
    $imageType = $_FILES['photoUpload']['type'];
    $imageTmp = $_FILES['photoUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $imageExt = strtolower(end(explode('.', $imageName)));
    $expensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");

    if(in_array($imageExt, $expensions)===false) {
        $errors[] = "Extensions not allowed. Only JPEG, JPG, PNG";
    }
    if($imageSize > 2097152) {
        $errors[] = "File size must not exceed 2MB";
    } else { print_r($errors); }
}
?>

<div class="col-md-4">
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="photoUpload"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
    <ul>
        <li>Sent File: <?php echo $imageName; ?></li>
        <li>File Size: <?php echo $imageSize; ?></li>
    </ul>
</form>
</div>
```

I know I lack something here like displaying it using echo and such. I also want it to be displayed in height & width = 200px; and border-radius: 50%;

Comment: I believe you can print the image like this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284713/how-to-display-or-preview-a-uploaded-image-after-submitted-in-php-without-save-t

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display or preview a uploaded image after submitted in PHP without save to database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284713/how-to-display-or-preview-a-uploaded-image-after-submitted-in-php-without-save-t)

Answer (score 0):

Are you saving the name of it in your database?

If so, try this below

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];      
$sql = "SELECT image FROM user WHERE `id` = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);                                            

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo "<div id='img_div'>";
        //img tag fetching from folder 'images' - change to match the file it was uploaded to
        echo "<img src='images/".$row['image']."' style='width:30%; height:30%;'>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

You will need to change the query to fit your code, but the idea should set you in the right direction.