# Submitting a file with ajax $.post "Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object"

Tags: jquery, json, multipartform-data, .post

I've been trying to submit a file with ajax `$.post`.

```
var json_data = update_json_({name:first_name+' '+last_name,email:email,email2:email2,tele:tele,message:message,cc:$("#cc<?php echo $rand; ?>").val(),scauth:'<?php echo $auth_code; ?>'});     
$.post
(
    '<?php echo PATH_TO_PROCESSING_SCRIPT; ?>?r=<?php echo $rand; ?>&nocache=' + Math.floor(Math.random()*1000), json_data,
    function(data)
    {
        // place the returned data in the results div
        $("#results<?php echo $rand; ?>").html(data);
        // div#response is returned by send.php. if the submission was successful, div#response will have the class ui-state-highlight. otherwise, the submission failed. Hide the form on success.
        if($("#response").hasClass('ui-state-highlight'))
        {
            $('#c-form<?php echo $rand; ?>').hide('slow');
        }
    }
); //close $.post
```

Here is the method that appends the `File` object onto a the [`javascript object`](http://www.w3schools.com/json/).

```
function update_json_(json_data)
{
    if(has_element("input[type=file]"))
    {
        var inputs = $("input[type=file]");
        fileobjs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
        {
            fileobjs.push(inputs.eq(i).prop("files")[0]);
        }
        $.extend(json_data, { files : fileobjs } );
    }
    return json_data;
}
```

But at the moment, I'm getting an error in firebug.

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object
[Break On This Error]   

...catch(c){return _.u}},stringify:function(f){function g(c){return h.call(this,c,a...
```

Comment: Ajax does not support file type, you have two choices here if you want to support only modern browsers which support File API use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) else need to look at jQuery plugins like [jQuery form](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Comment: Can you please provide an example or another link? :O (with file upload) so I can put it into perceptive, Thanks :)

Comment: which model are you looking for... FormData or plugin

Comment: I'm not really constricted on either, but preferably one that supports more than the other.

Comment: Please check this, it should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046684/php-file-upload-using-jquery-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided on just using the `$.ajaxForm()` library from [malsup](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use form data. . .

```
function update_json_(json_data)
{
    if(has_element("input[type=file]"))
    {
        var inputs = $("input[type=file]");
        fileobjs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
        {
            fileobjs.push(inputs.eq(i).prop("files")[0]);
        }
        $.extend(json_data, { files : fileobjs } );
    }

    //add your files to form data. . 
    var fd = new FormData();    
    fd.append( 'files', fileobject );

    //similarly add your other data using fd.put('key', 'val');
    .
    . 

    //return data to be sent
    return fd;
}
```

Comment: does the information in `json_data` get submitted along with `fd`?

Comment: No, you need to add all key value pair to fd ushing fd.append('key', 'value');

Comment: I've just written a new `update_json_` method, with the semantics from your suggestion. But for some reason the `$_FILES` php variable is empty upon submission.

Comment: the data will be received as multipart-data or multimedia. .
Just put console.log(fd); before sending data, and check it in console to conform that at sending we have files in that.