# How can I send input file without form tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, input

I am trying to send file to server with HTML and JavaScript. The scenario like below :

1. user clicks some button and it shows a div pop up.
2. user inputs file with `<input type='file'>`.
3. user presses button.
4. send data to server and div pop up closes.

Note that all of these actions happen in one page. Only div pop up can be open and closed.

At first, I was trying to send data with a `<form>` tag, and it works fine. The problem is when I submit the form it changes the page.

So what I am trying to do is sending file data without using a `form` tag. I have searched web, it looks somehow impossible. Is there any alternative way to send file data in div pop up?

Thanks :D

Comment: You're trying to solve the problem the wrong way: the solution is not to remove the form but to prevent the form from submitting and send the data with Ajax instead. It's definitely not impossible.

Comment: Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: You can do this with the help of jQuery Ajax.

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` stop your page refreshed on submit event;

Comment: As above, the form is not the issue.  You just don't want to navigate away from the page, so deal with that instead.  This will do exactly what you need... https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: @jogesh_pi but doesn't send the form neither

Comment: @kpull1, Sorry my mistake i didn't discribe about the plugin, For file or Upload images i used this plugin, http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ which will do the things accordingly.

Comment: @jogesh_pi `malsup's jquery.form` is a simple and good one I use too

Comment: @jogesh_pi I've not seen that before, but I've only needed such things for progress bars for file uploads, so I used the one I linked above.  For regular forms I'd obviously just serialize and use ajax, but that looks very handy.  Thanks for my new thing for the day :)

Comment: Thanks for all. But is there any chance to implement this function without additional add-ons? Since I am not free to use those with project political issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered doing it via JQuery?

You can post the values like this without a refresh:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
   $.post('/url/to/your/function', {'post': value}, function(data){
      if(data !== 0) {

      }
   }, "json");
});
```

You can find more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

**Edit:**

It's not possible to upload files with jQuery $.post, neverthless, with the file API and XMLHttpRequest, it's perfectly possible to upload a file in AJAX, and you can even know how much data have been uploaded yet…

```
$('input').change(function() 
{
    var fileInput = document.querySelector('#file');

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/upload/');

xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) 
{
    /* 
    * values that indicate the progression
    * e.loaded
    * e.total
    */
};

xhr.onload = function()
{
    alert('upload complete');
};

// upload success
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0))
{
    // if your server sends a message on upload sucess, 
    // get it with xhr.responseText
    alert(xhr.responseText);
}

var form = new FormData();
form.append('title', this.files[0].name);
form.append('pict', fileInput.files[0]);

xhr.send(form);
}
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046684/php-file-upload-using-jquery-post)

Comment: How do you post a file with ajax?

Comment: I see now that OP has changed the question into a file upload, that wasn't the question at first ;)

Comment: Nope - it said that from the very beginning, before the edit ;)

Comment: Ah ok, didn't noticed it. I changed my answer into hopefully something usefull for OP :)

Comment: Thanks for your code, but the biggest issue here is file uploading:)

Comment: second option after edit.. you use formdata which use form tag ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a trick. It works, but I am not sure it is good way or not.

As you recommended, I use jQuery and ajax.

```
function sendUpgradeReq(id){
    var url = '/api/update.json';
    var form = $("#upgradeFrm");
    var data = new FormData(form[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'post',
        dataType    : 'json',
        url         : url,
        data        : data,
        enctype     : "multipart/form-data",
        cache       : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        success     : function(data) {
            alert('Success!');
            $('#applyPop').css('display', 'none');
        },
        complete : function(data) {

        },
        error : function(data, status, error) {
            alert('Fail! :<');
            e.preventDefaultEvent();
        }
    });
}
```

I thought the most important part here is `new FormData()`. It takes complete file information from `<input type='file'>`.

Thanks :D